# Yii2: How to make inline radioList with HtmlHelpers

Tags: php, yii2

I have this radioList:

```
Html::radioList('name,null,$array['class' => 'form-control']);
```

It genegated vertical radioList, but I want it horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?=Html::activeRadioList($model, $attribute, [1 => 'option1', 2 => 'option2'], [
        'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
            return '<label class="radio-inline">' . Html::radio($name, $checked, ['value'  => $value]) . $label . '</label>';
        }
    ])?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Code only answers aren't welcomed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 Its works. But small clarification here if attribute name was different means value is not selected properly. For example model attribute name is address but in html given for address1 for this case not selected the radiobox. Is there any options for checked=checked.

Comment: You can use [`Html::label()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#label()-detail) as well.